Authenticate to spring boot web server through desktop swing app
I have spun up a very basic spring boot app and implemented authentication. I can login to the page through spring boot's login page.
My security config is
    return https.
            authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                                          .requestMatchers("/", "/public/**", "/error", "/webjars/**")
                                          .permitAll()
                                          .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/contact")
                                          .permitAll()
                                          .requestMatchers("/loggedin/**").authenticated()
                                 ).
            formLogin(form -> form
                              .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                              .failureHandler(authenticationFailed)
                              .successHandler(authenticationSuccessful)
                     ).
            logout(logout -> logout
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .permitAll()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/logged_out")
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutComponent)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                  ).
            sessionManagement(session -> session
                                      .invalidSessionUrl("/login")
                                      .sessionFixation()
                                      .migrateSession()
                                      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                                      .maximumSessions(1)
                                      .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                                      .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                                      .expiredUrl("/logout")
                             ).
            headers(headers -> headers
                            .httpStrictTransportSecurity(security -> security
                                                                 .includeSubDomains(true)
                                                                 .maxAgeInSeconds(60 * 60 * 28)
                                                        )
                            .xssProtection(Customizer.withDefaults())
                   ).
            build();

And authentication doesn't even use db but instead has just one user
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    String name     = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    if (name.equals("Test") && password.equals("Test")) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    throw new BadCredentialsException("Failed login! Try again.");
}

Now I would like to create a desktop app to login to the spring server.
Sadly I can not find any resources on how to implement login request. I have made a simple window that has username and password fields, but I do not know what action to take when login is pressed in order to authenticate. Also should I disable some security setting in order to allow logging in from desktop app to work? Is there any resource

you do a POST request to /login containing FORMDATA (not json) which is basically in the body, parameters separated by ampersands for instance: username=foobar&password=password123 that is why it is named FormLogin in spring

@Toerktumlare I do a POST but data send matches that of a GET no? With GET I usually include username=foobar&password=password123 in the url as a parameter, but I can do same in the POST too? Sorry I am not well versed enough hence why I am asking.

POST is for posting data, GET is for getting data. If you pass data in the body of a GET request according to the http standard, the values in the body may be ignored. If you make a GET request against login, you will get the default login page. If you POST against it,, it will try to authenticate with the data supplied in the body.
